# Parsley checkbox validation

Tags: html, forms, validation, parsley.js

I have multiple checkboxes that I need at least on to be checked. But for some reason Parsley doesn't recognize it as a validation.

```
<div class="form-check"><input name="tags" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="spelling"><label class="form-check-label" for="spelling" required="">Spelling</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input name="tags" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="grammatica"><label class="form-check-label" for="grammatica">Grammatica</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input name="tags" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="woordenschat"><label class="form-check-label" for="woordenschat">Woordenschat</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input name="tags" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="begrijpend_lezen"><label class="form-check-label" for="begrijpend_lezen">Begrijpend Lezen</label></div>
<div class="form-check"><input name="tags" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="opdrachten"><label class="form-check-label" for="opdrachten">Opdrachten</label></div>
```

I can't find any good examples on how to properly do this.

Answer (score 0):

http://parsleyjs.org/doc/examples/simple.html, the checkbox group has the exact thing done.